# linear regression with dummy as dependent variable

Tags: python, regression, linear-regression, statsmodels

I have a dataset where my variable of interest is a dummy, and I would like to do a linear regression on it. However when I use the "R-style formula" in `statsmodels` OLS, it gives me an error.

This is the code I'm using:

```
mod = smf.ols("C(cured) ~ Loan_Term + Loan_Amount", data=df)
result = mod.fit()
```

But even when I run the first line, the error says the following:

```
ValueError: endog has evaluated to an array with multiple columns that has shape (17314,2). This occurs when the variable converted to endog is non-numeric (eg. bool or str).
```

Tried using `Loan_Amount` as dependent variable just to see if the problem was in my whole dataset and it worked.. so I assume the problem is with the dependen variable being dummy? Can that be solved?

Also tried it with the regular way of doing the regression:

```
mod = sm.OLS(Y,X)
```

and that works...

Any ideas?

Comment: You are trying to predict a categorical variable in a linear regression.. i dont think tats gonna work.. categorical variable can be independent variables on the RHS.. if you want to determine categorical variables from set of inputs you should better go for classification ML algorithms..

Comment: @ArunKalirajaBaskaran I know for a fact you can use it. Not the optimal maybe but the simplest and I need to use it. Also i dont know what RHS is

Comment: In OLS the dependent variable needs to be numeric and univariate. It will work if you create your own 0-1 dummy variable. Patsy when using formulas creates a two-column categorical dummy encoding which does not work for OLS

Comment: @Josef You mean just running "cured" instead of C(cured)? I tried! Still same result..

Comment: "cured" has to be numeric with values like 0 and 1. If it's strings or objects, then the formula interprets it as categorical also without the `C`

Comment: @Josef yeah it's 1 and 0, but still doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: @Josef Nevermind. Realized that the dtype of the column was "O" instead of int or float. So I changed that and it's solved.